# Using COM object from PowerBuilder - error 36: name not found accessing external object

Tags: com, automation, ole, powerbuilder

I'm trying to access a third-party COM server from within Powerbuilder. I can instantiate the object but whenever I try to call a method or a property on the object I get error 36: "name not found accessing external object".

```
OLEObject PNSession
PNSession = CREATE OLEObject
ll_status = PNSession.ConnectToNewObject("PNSrv9.PNSession")
if ll_status = 0 then
    // Set the session printer
    try
       PNSession.SetSessionPrinter('TIFF Image Printer 9.0', 1, g_pfapp.null_string, False)
    catch (oleruntimeerror lole_error2)
        messagebox('Set Error', lole_error2.description)
    end try

    // Turn job tracking on
    PNSession.TrackingOn = True
end if
```

The ConnectToNewObject call succeeds and I see the COM server in my Task Manager, but subsequent calls fail. The above looks correct based on all the COM automation code samples for Word, Excel that I looked at.

The COM server is a C++ ATL COM Server, not a .NET COM object if that makes any difference.

Does anyone have an idea why this isn't working or what I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: This might be a misleading error message. IIRC, if the COM server throws an exception, it might cause PB to think the call failed for the wrong reason. According to [SetSessionPrinter](http://st3.peernet.com/developer/printers/com/pnsrv9guide/index.html?ipnsession_setsessionprinter.htm) documentation, it might throw for several reasons. Are you sure it doesn't? I know being sure here is hard, but at least according to the specified conditions for throwing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have the parameter types correct. Looking at [SetSessionPrinter](http://www.peernet.com/developer/printers/com/pnsrv9guide/index.html?object_reference.htm), I would try passing `0` for `PortsPreCreated`. For `PortBaseName` try a string initialized to `""` and also try `0`.

Similarly, try `PNSession.TrackingOn = 0`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was working on this problem with a client and they have changed their approach so as to not use the COM object from within Powerbuilder. I will keep you suggestions in mind for in-house testing.